# Buffer Overflow Attack with Int

Tags: arrays, c, buffer-overflow

```
char c[10];
int value = 1;
```

Why the value changes to 0 until I enter 12 chars? Why is 12 not 10 or 11? (I know the terminator and how it pushed to the next memory space)

Comment: Hi, how are you reading the string `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects of a given type are typically placed at memory locations that are a multiple of the object size, i.e. the object is *aligned* to a boundary matching its size.

An `int` is typically 4 bytes in size.  If `c` is placed before `value` in memory, and if `c` started at a 4 byte offset, then there will be two bytes of padding between them.  This would explain why `value` doesn't get overwritten unless more than 12 bytes or more are written to `c`.

Note also that this is all [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as far as the C standard is concerned, however for the purpose of exploiting vulnerabilities it can be useful to examine what specific implementations do under certain conditions.

Comment: @Shaobo 12593 in hex is 0x3131, i.e. two bytes with the value 49